# Change permission of a directory and subdirectories with xargs and chmod commands in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, unix

i have a list of directories in the current directory named with there permission codes (exemple : 552, 700, 777). I want to get the code permission from the name of directory and apply it to the directory and all the files it contains.

I tried with the xargs command :
`find . -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -type d | xargs chmod -R [0-9][0-9][0-9]`

the problem with this command it takes the first directory and its change the permission code of all directories.

```css
├── 555
│   └── logs
│       ├── 01.log
│       ├── 02.log
│       ├── 03.log
│       ├── 04.log
│       ├── 05.log
│       ├── 06.log
│       └── 07.log
├── 700
│   └── data
│       └── data1.data
```

what I want : I have the 555 directory so I want to change all sub files and directory with permission code 555 and for the second directory I want to change all the subfiles and directory with the permission code 700

what my command do: it change all other files and subdirectories with the permission code of the first file 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -type d  | sed 's#\./\(.*\)#\1#' | xargs -I{} chmod -R {} {}
```

- the `find` is the same as yours.
- the `sed` is added to remove the `./` from the directory name.  Find returns `./700`, `./555`, ...
- `xargs` with `-I` uses `{}` to reuse what it received into the command.  So it says "`chmod -R` DIRNAME DIRNAME".  So `chmod -R 700 700` and so on.
- In your attempt, `xargs chmod -R [0-9][0-9][0-9]`, there is nothing to link the [0-9] in the `find` to the [0-9] in `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Without xargs

```
find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[0-9]\{3\}$"| awk -F"/" '{print "chmod -R " $NF,$0}'|sh
```

Answer (score 0):

find:

```
find . -type d -name '[0-7][0-7][0-7]' \
-exec sh -c 'for i do chmod -R "${i##*/}" "$i"; done' _ {} +
```

or a bash loop:

```
shopt -s globstar

for i in **/[0-7][0-7][0-7]/; do
    i=${i%/}
    chmod -R "${i##*/}" "$i"; done
done
```